# How to read images in a file consecutively without sort functions?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm new at image processing, I captured frames from a video and I want to convert them into arrays. These frames must be consecutive.
here's the part of my code

```
folder = "/content/otherGrayscaleImage"
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))]

print("Working with {0} images".format(len(onlyfiles)))

for i in range(len(onlyfiles)):
    #do something
    print(onlyfiles[i])
```

here is the output

```
Working with 328 images
241.png
312.png
27.png
149.png
42.png
296.png
182.png
99.png
64.png
120.png
102.png
208.png
79.png
325.png
......
```

as you can see, the print of my outputs is random and does not start from my first image which is *1.png*.

here is the sorted input using .sorted() function.

```
1.png
10.png
100.png
101.png
.
.
199.png
2.png
```

my ultimate goal is to convert 64 successive 2d images array into a 3d array, to achieve that python should read my images consecutively; but it doesn't.

how should I read my images in a file consecutively?

PS: using sorting functions such as sorted() would not help

Comment: Sort the list of filenames before you iterate over it.

Comment: Sort by increasing numerical value of the filename (extension removed).

Comment: already did, just didn't mention it.

Comment: So what more do you want ?

Comment: my sorted data inside the folder is sorted like this: 1 10 100 101

Comment: In the future, when you want to number files and be able to easily sort them, use fixed number of digits with 0 padding -- i.e. `001.png`, `010.png`, etc.

Comment: This is not a sort by numerical value. (2 comes before 10).

Comment: I want to read my data like this: 1. 2. 3.  ..... 328.

Comment: What stops you from sorting this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom sort key. The manual solution is something like this:

```
onlyfiles.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[:x.index('.')]))
```

This is not a robust solution. If you have any files that have anything other than integers before the extension, or are missing an extension, this will raise an error.

Luckily, there is a library called [natsort](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/) that catches the corner cases of human sorting pretty well. After `pip install natsort`, you can do

```
from natsort import natsorted

onlyfiles = natsorted(onlyfiles)
```

Mandatory disclaimer: I am not affiliated with natsort except as a satisfied user.

Comment: Why cluttering the application with an extra module when a one-liner does the trick ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust. It's a really robust module, so seems like a valid option to share.

Comment: Robust ? Is the built-in sort of Python not "robust" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust. The key function I suggest certainly is not. It's incredibly fickle and will crash on any accidentally placed file that doesn't match the expected pattern.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. I added the caveats to the answer. Hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: No crash, but a well deserved error condition. Certainly better than silent agreement.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Fair enough. Updated that wording too